# Can I make react-navigation use a hash url?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

By default, react-navigation forms normal url paths when navigating.  This means I have to configure my server to make sure paths that my app uses are routed only to my app bundle, which is kind of limiting and requires special considerations in hosting.

What I'd like to do is configure it like react-router's HashRouter, where the specific route is after a hash, like:

https://example.com/#/path/to/route

I see no documentation in react-navigation describing a mode like this.

I tried putting a # in my top-level paths, but it seems to be trying to do me a favor and url-protects the # by turning it into %23, which defeats the purpose.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At Core, React Navigation doesn't support URLs including hash for universal linking.

Assuming that you have set up and configured your app for universal linking.

Detect when the app opened with a universal link  (https://example.com/#/path/to/route) then manually navigate to a specific screen corresponding to that URL.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const deepLinkToScreen = async () => {
    // Get the deep link used to open the app
    const initialUrl = await Linking.getInitialURL();

    if (initialUrl !== null) {
      // The app opened via universal/deep link. 
      // Parse initialUrl and extract parameters and more
      

      navigation.navigate("[SPECIFIC_SCREEN_NAME_FOR_THIS_URL]");
    }
  };

  deepLinkToScreen();
}, []);
```

Comment: I should have clarified this is purely for web use.  I'm not trying to support a deep link in a phone app.

Comment: I think this will work for a single top-level reload, but if the path is deeper is there a way to get react-navigation to cascade the url processing?

Comment: I was hoping getStateFromPath would be my hook, but it appears to lop off the hash.  This works for my immediate purpose, so I'll mark as correct.

Comment: For deeply nested routes, it going to be a challenge. Try to flatten your navigation routes specific to this kind of screen which required universal linking